# Why is the right side of a pipeline dying if the left side process receives SIGINT?

Tags: bash, signals

I was playing with capturing a process logs to a file while the process receives SIGINT signal for debugging.

```
 timeout -s INT 2 ./myprogram 2>&1 | tee /tmp/1
```

What I found out, is that when I sent SIGINT to the process on the left side of the pipeline, the right side process *also* receives SIGINT, which makes `tee` exit and logs are missing. This is surprising to me. I made the following script to reproduce it:

```
$ timeout -s INT 1 bash -xc 'trap "echo LEFT SIGINT >&2; sleep 1" INT; sleep infinity' | bash -xc 'trap "echo RIGHT SIGINT" INT; sleep infinity'
+ trap 'echo RIGHT SIGINT' INT
+ sleep infinity
+ trap 'echo LEFT SIGINT >&2; sleep 1' INT
+ sleep infinity
++ echo LEFT SIGINT
++ echo RIGHT SIGINT
RIGHT SIGINT
LEFT SIGINT
++ sleep 1
```

The script runs on the left side `timeout -s INT 1` which will sent a SIGINT signal after 1 second, to a process `bash` that registers a `INT` trap handler and sleeps infinitely, waiting to be killed. The right side also runs bash with a trap on `INT` and sleeps infinitely. My shell is Bash5.2.26.

Both processes received SIGINT, yet it was sent only the left process.

Why does the right process receive SIGINT?

Comment: Very strange. Not just SIGINT, the same happens with SIGUSR1, probably any signal.

Comment: Yes, the same with `SIGALRM`.

Comment: Does this question answer yours? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17330/1655

Comment: Best guess is that it's caused by Bash putting all of the processes in a pipeline in the same process group when job control is enabled, partly to ensure that all of the processes see the same signals.  If you put your `timeout ...` example code in a file and run it with `bash` then only `LEFT SIGINT` is printed.  That's because job control is disabled by default for non-interactive shells.  If you enable job control by putting `set -o monitor` on the first line of the file then you get the same behaviour as for the interactive shell if you run it.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a behavior of `timeout`.  When I `strace` a run of it (version of GNU coreutils 8.30), I observe that in addition to signaling the child process it is monitoring, it also sends the same signal to its own whole process group.

I also see that it sends not only the requested signal, but also a `SIGCONT`, which I presume is to ensure that the recipients receive the primary signal in the event that they are stopped.

I don't see any way to prevent `timeout` from doing this, so if it's causing you trouble then you'll need to work around it or avoid `timeout`.

Answer (score 3):

When job control is enabled, both LEFT and RIGHT processes are part of the same process group, which is the reason why they both receive INT signal.

You can disable job control by `set +m` to observe different behaviour.

Comment: Also, job control is normally disabled in scripts. So the problem only impacts interactive use of `timeout`.